# Parse Javascript date to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have date object in JavaScript which give me: `"Wed Oct 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200"`;

I try to parse it but I get an exception:

```
string Date = "Wed Oct 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200";
DateTiem d = DateTime.ParseExact(Date,
                                 "ddd MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss GMTzzzzz", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`MM` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier) is `2` digit month number from `01` to `12`.

You need to use [`MMM` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMM_Specifier) instead for abbreviated name of month.

And for your `+0200` part, you need to use [`K` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#KSpecifier) which has time zone information instead of `zzzzz`.

And you need to use single quotes for your `GMT` part as `'GMT'` to specify it as literal string delimiter.

```
string s = "Wed Oct 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Any [`z` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zSpecifier) is not recommended with `DateTime` parsing. Because they represents [signed offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of local time zone UTC value and this specifier doesn't effect [`DateTime.Kind` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx). And `DateTime` doesn't keep any offset value.

That's why this specifier fits with [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) parsing instead.